# $Resource Delete wont work correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm having issues getting the delete to work.

this is my resource:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("common.services")
    .factory("complainantResource",
            ["$resource",
                "appSettings",
                complainantResource])

function complainantResource($resource, appSettings) {


    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/complainants/:id", null,
        {
            'update': { method: 'PUT' },
            'delete': { method: 'DELETE' }
        });
}
}());
```

If I try to do a $update, it works fine. If I try to do a $delete, I get a can't do it on a null or undefined error.

```
                 vm.complainants.$delete({ id: vm.futureDeleteID },
                    function success() {

                        console.log("deleted");

                    },
                    function fail() {

                        console.log("error");
                    });
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? I've looked at examples, im not sure what I'm doing differently.

Comment: Check your browser's *Network* console and look for the `DELETE` request. Check that the URL is correct (should be `.../api/complainants/someFutureDeletedID`). What is the response from that request?

Comment: Not even getting to that point unfortunately

Comment: Oh, in that case, post the full error message. Sounds like it's just a scripting issue